Higher order generalization of inversions of permutations?
Usual definition of inversion: Let $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ be a permutation, i.e., a bijection on $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. An inversion of $f$, is a pair $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$, s.t. $f(i) > f(j)$.
For example, if $n=3$ and $f = (1,3,2)$, i.e., $f(1) = 3, f(3) = 2, f(2) = 1$, then $f$ has the following inversions
$$
(1,2),(1,3).
$$
Restatement of inversion: We restate the definition of inversion, so that it can be generalized. Write $S_2 = \{identity,swap\}$ as the symmetric group on $[2]$. Let $f:[n]\rightarrow [n]$ be a permutation on $n$ as above. For $\sigma \in S_2$, we say the pair $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$, is a $\sigma$-inversion of $f$ if $(f(i),f(j))$ and $\sigma(1),\sigma(2)$ share the same ordering of natural numbers, that is, if
$$
f(i) < f(j) \iff \sigma(1) < \sigma(2).
$$
In this language, an ordinary inversion of $f$ is nothing but a $swap$-inversion of $f$. And a non-inversion of $f$, i.e., a pair $(i,j)$ s.t. $i<j$ and $f(i)<f(j)$, is exactly an $identity$-inversion of $f$.
Generalization of inversion: The notion of $\sigma$-inversion, generalizes easily to higher order symmetric groups. For example, Let $\sigma : [3] \rightarrow [3]$ be a permutation of $[3]$. A $\sigma$-inversion of $f$, is a triple $(i,j,k)$ with $1 \le i < j < k \le n$, s.t. $(f(i),f(j),f(k))$ and $(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3))$ share the same ordering, that is,
$$
f(i) < f(j) \iff \sigma(1) < \sigma(2), \quad and \quad f(i) < f(k) \iff \sigma(1) < \sigma(3), \quad and \quad f(j) < f(k) \iff \sigma(2) < \sigma(3).
$$
A soft question: Are such kind of generalization of inversions ever studied in the literature? If they are, could you please provid with any reference?
A precise question: For $f \in S_n$, the permutation group of $[n]$, let $n_f$ be the number of inversions of $f$. It is known that (see https://oeis.org/A008302)
$$
\sum_{f \in S_n} x^{n_f} = (1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\dots(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{n-1}).
$$
This result in essence determines the number of permutations $f$ having $k$ inversions. The qeustion is, can this result be extended to $S_3$-inversions?
Thank you.

@JaapScherphuis. Thanks. I will correct this.
